# Insert Operation Failed for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to insert some rows into SQL server database and throws an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'null' to data type bit

Could anyone explain what is this for?

This is not in a program.

Comment: Sounds like you aren't inserting null, but the word 'null'. If bit column is nullable, then you should be able to insert actual `null` not `'null'`, otherwise, insert 0 or 1.

Comment: Please post the structure of table you're inserting into and the `INSERT` statement you attempted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert a null value into a column, you need to write `NULL`, and not `'NULL'` (wrapping it in quotes indicates that it is a VARCHAR containing the letters N, U, L L - not a null value).

That is what the error message is telling you: you're trying to insert the VARCHAR value `'NULL'` into a column that will only accept bit data.

Change the `'NULL'` in your insert query to `NULL`.

You need something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TableName(ColumnName) VALUES(NULL); --this is the right way
```

Instead of this:

```
INSERT INTO TableName(ColumnName) VALUES('NULL'); --this is the wrong way
```

Answer (score 0):

What you might be trying

```
INSERT INTO TESTTABLE(BITCOLUMN) VALUES('NULL')
```

What should it actually be..

```
INSERT INTO TESTTABLE(BITCOLUMN) VALUES(NULL)
```